# Searching through JSON result in Vue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

I get an array like this from the googlemaps API:

```
  "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "Blasieholmsgatan",
            "short_name" : "Blasieholmsgatan",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Norrmalm",
            "short_name" : "Norrmalm",
            "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Stockholm",
            "short_name" : "Stockholm",
            "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Stockholms län",
            "short_name" : "Stockholms län",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Sverige",
            "short_name" : "SE",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "111 48",
            "short_name" : "111 48",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ],
      "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"street-address\"\u003eBlasieholmsgatan\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"postal-code\"\u003e111 48\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eStockholm\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eSverige\u003c/span\u003e",
      "formatted_address" : "Blasieholmsgatan, 111 48 Stockholm, Sverige",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 59.3300268,
            "lng" : 18.0767623
         },
         "viewport" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 59.3313757802915,
               "lng" : 18.07811128029151
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 59.32867781970849,
               "lng" : 18.0754133197085
            }
         }
      },
      "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
      "id" : "13f208be3747ee13670af15b7a3aa838ef511659",
      "name" : "Blasieholmsgatan",
      "place_id" : "ChIJ1UFulFmdX0YRBL2RMqWlm-8",
      "reference" : "CmRbAAAAcNWeXrQZ7dVVRpjNHcDUsgCrzIwy6au7GoIoEylqnOpAk1RitdeEq89rYUd9SRtXiZWK6gC6c46bXiV4k5rDljoQ6_Tk2UKBcZshv3LcwRJbnXJqPiMJwE_qxrxquRH7EhAaye_BQjF-Yff_yulQotQZGhTn5DDbhets_MnS-wbn5gl7EPQx0A",
      "scope" : "GOOGLE",
      "types" : [ "route" ],
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?q=Blasieholmsgatan,+111+48+Stockholm,+Sverige&ftid=0x465f9d59946e41d5:0xef9ba5a53291bd04",
      "utc_offset" : 60,
      "vicinity" : "Norrmalm"

   }
```

And what I want is the value off `long_name` in the object where `type` is `"postal_town"`.

I was trying to do it like this:

```
method(place){
        place.address_components.forEach(m => {
                if (m.types == "postal_town"){
                    return m.long_name;
                }
            });
        return "I fucked up!";
    }
```

Is there a problem because of the types being an array or am I just doing it wrong? It should be able to find types, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In:

```
"address_components" : [
     ...
     {
        "long_name" : "Stockholm",
        "short_name" : "Stockholm",
        "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
     },
```

`types` is an array, to look for values in it, use [`types.includes(value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), not `==`.

Also, returning in [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not do what you think it does. Since you are looking for a value inside the `address_components` array, your best bet is to use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `.forEach()`:

```
method(place) {
  let placeFound = place.address_components.find(m => m.types.includes("postal_town"));
  if (placeFound) {
    return placeFound.long_name;
  }
  return "I fucked up!";
}
```

Demo JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/50wL7mdz/148305/

Comment: Thanks alot, just what I was looking for ^_^